# Convert python dict "key value" into dict having "k(value) ey"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have a dict

```
d = {'A1BB11': 10,  
     'B1CC55': 20,  
     'A1A11':  30,  
     'A1A21':  40,  
     'B1HH21': 50,  
     'C1KK88': 60
    }
```

I want to get a new dict from prev dict d

```
new_d = {'A1(80)':['BB11', 'A11', 'A21'],  
         'B1(70)':['CC55', 'HH21'],  
         'C1(60)':['KK88']  
        }
```

Could you provide a simple pythonic way to it? I am new to python world.

Comment: Is it always grouped on the first two letters?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to create two dictionaries to track the two values you're concerned with: the sums and the lists of suffixes.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d1, d2 = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(list)

d = {'A1BB11': 10,  
     'B1CC55': 20,  
     'A1A11':  30,  
     'A1A21':  40,  
     'B1HH21': 50,  
     'C1KK88': 60
    }

for k, v in d.items():
    prefix = k[:2]
    d1[prefix] += v
    d2[prefix].append(k[2:])

final = {'{}({})'.format(k, d1[k]): v for k, v in d2.items()}

print(final)
# {'A1(80)': ['BB11', 'A11', 'A21'],
#  'B1(70)': ['CC55', 'HH21'],
#  'C1(60)': ['KK88']}
```

Comment: When I try to upload **final** into a column, for eg 
df.loc[df['ColA'].str.contains('value', na=False), 'ColB'] = final
I get following error
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. 
Could you help me handle this error